# Yii2: how to pass object to module

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

let's say I'm making ecommerce app with Yii2 and would like to implement all payment methods as modules.

After order has been confirmed by user, I would like to redirect user to payment process. I have following code in my CheckoutController:

```
        if($order->save())
        {
            $module = Yii::$app->getModule('payment');
            $module->init();
        }
```

At this point I would like to share current Order `$order` instance with `payment` module. 
What would be the best approach to do this?

I've looked through docs but did not find anything relevant.

Thank you!

Comment: I would say something like `$module->setOrder($order);`.

Comment: I declare public property in module ``public $order;``, define a method in module ``public function setOrder($order){ $this->order = $order; }``, then in Controller I set this property via ``$module->setOrder($order)`` before ``$module->init()``, but when I do ``var_dump($order)`` in module ``init()`` method, it returns ``NULL``

Comment: it appears ``getModule()`` actually runs ``Payment::init()`` method, therefore ``$order`` property is set by ``setOrder`` _after_ module has been run. Is it possible to instantiate module first, then set ``$order`` property, then run ``init()`` method?

Comment: I've done this as a workaround, but it looks ugly: ``public function init(){ parent::init(); if(!isset($this->order)){ return; }``

Comment: If I recall correctly Yii runs `init()` automatically. But why can't you set a `setOrder($order);` and then something like `process()`or `run()` or whatever to process the payment?

Comment: good point! I think it solves the issue. Would you like to put your comments as a solution so I could accept it?

Comment: I created an answer from this comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your payment module create a method `setOrder($order)` which sets the current order, checks if it is an instance of `Order` and so on.

Create another method like `process()` which does the payment processing. You should check here, if the `$order` is properly set.

You can then do in your `CheckoutController`:

```
if ($order->save())
{
    $module = Yii::$app->getModule('payment');
    $module->init(); // I believe yii calls this automatically
    $module->setOrder($order);
    $module->process();
}
```

Comment: It does call ``init()`` automatically, so this is not necessary here. But your solution is perfect. Thank you!